# Subtract Time Values in R

Tags: r, date, time

I have Values such as :

```
df[,1:2]
```

Results in [image]

I want to create a new column that has the difference between the Ins and Outs.
These are TIME values,
Expected output is :

1201
0718 ( neglecting Negative values )
.. and So on.

Comment: `df$diff <- df$In - df$Out` ?

Comment: Gives the difference only, not in the 24 hour format. @OttoKässi

Comment: Convert first `In` and `Out` as `date-time` objects and then use [difftime()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html)

Comment: How do I do that? @ANG

Comment: What do `143` and `1344` mean as `In` and `Out`?

Comment: Both Imply as "01:43" and "13:44" @ANG

Comment: And what's about the date?

Comment: I don't need the date. I never mentioned it @ANG

Comment: So how do you deal with the second row for instance where In = "12:39" and Out = "5:21"?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)

# generate few rows of data
In <- c('143','1239')
Out <- c('1344','521')
df <- data.frame(cbind(In, Out), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# pad with zero if needed (e.g. 143 -> 0143)
df$In[str_length(df$In) == 3] <- paste(0,df$In[str_length(df$In) == 3], sep='')
df$Out[str_length(df$Out) == 3] <- paste(0,df$Out[str_length(df$Out) == 3], sep='')

df$In <- strptime(df$In, format='%H%M')
df$Out <- strptime(df$Out, format='%H%M')

df$diff <- df$In - df$Out
```

This gives:

```
> df$diff
Time differences in hours
[1] -12.01667   7.30000
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes but shouldn't it be like 0730 ?

Comment: The difference between 13:44 and 05:21 is 7 hours and 18 minutes, or 7.3 hours.

Comment: @OttoKässi Thanks for helping OP in this but I can't figure out the logic of doing the difference between In and Out times without considering dates. How do you deal with a situation where In = "12:39" and Out = "5:21"? For OP, the difference is 7.3 hours but I believe this is not true if you assume that the In times come before the Out times

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to compute the *absolute* time difference where the *time of the day* (neglecting the date) is given as character strings in the form `HMM` or `HHMM`.

There are classes which support time of the day (without date) directly, e.g., the `hms` package or the `ITime` class of the `data.table` package.

As an additional challenge, the timestamps are not given in a standard time format `HH:MM`, e.g., `09:43`.

Here is an approach which uses `as.ITime()` after the strings have been padded.

```
# create sample data frame
df <- data.frame(In  = c("143", "1239"), 
                 Out = c("1344", "521"))

library(magrittr)   # piping is used for readability

# pad strings and coerce to ITime class
df$In %<>% 
  stringr::str_pad(4L, pad = "0") %>% 
  data.table::as.ITime("%H%M")
df$Out %<>% 
  stringr::str_pad(4L, pad = "0") %>% 
  data.table::as.ITime("%H%M")

# compute absolute difference
df$absdiff <- abs(df$In - df$Out)

df
```

> ```
>         In      Out  absdiff
> 1 01:43:00 13:44:00 12:01:00
> 2 12:39:00 05:21:00 07:18:00
> ```

Now, the OP seems to expect the result in the same non-standard format `HHMM` (without the `:` field separator) as the input values. This can be achieved by

```
df$absdiff %>% 
  as.POSIXct() %>% 
  format("%H%M")
```

> ```
> [1] "1201" "0718"
> ```